# Do we need [embedded-agent]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [embedded-agent](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-agent) tag has been around for a while, but it doesn't seem to be a great tag in its current state:

- There is no tag wiki or excerpt.
- The highest [search result for 'IoT embedded agent'](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=iot+embedded+agent) is a Stack Exchange question.
- The term does not have a clearly defined meaning in the context of the site.
- The tag seems to be confused with embedded computing in one question.

Should we narrow down the tag scope and keep the tag, remove it completely or just leave it as is?

Comment: Maybe you should ask [the guy who added the tag](http://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/143/revisions)? I understand the term, I think the concept is well-defined, but I'm not convinced of the utility of the tag.

Comment: @Gilles: Heh. I can't remember why I used that tag. How strange. I'll just go ahead and remove it then, since that's the only question now using it (there was another one, but it's been edited by you).